# How to distinct more than one column using SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    MRP.[date], FT.feedtype, ROUND(MRP.rateperkg, 3) AS Rateperkg 
FROM 
    K_FS_FeedMrpDetails MRP 
INNER join 
    K_FPS_feedtype FT ON FT.sno = MRP.feedtype 
WHERE
    MRP.[date] BETWEEN '2013-08-09 00:00:00.000' AND '2014-08-25 00:00:00.000' 
    AND  MRP.state = 1  
    AND MRP.rateperkg != 0
GROUP BY 
    ft.feedtype,mrp.rateperkg 
ORDER BY
    MRP.[date] desc
```

In my query has same column values feedtype and rateperkg..

Comment: Add `mrp.date` as well in the `group by` clause. With `group by` no need to use `distinct`.

Comment: `DISTINCT` is **always** applied to **all columns** in your `SELECT` statement anyway....

Comment: Do not use `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY` together. As you have no aggregate function in the select list you should only use `DISTINCT` in this case. Please post some sample data so we can understand what you are trying to explain.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use distinct with group by together. when you use distinct in your select SQL Server apply distinct to all column of your select query.